# How to show the detail of a row in react table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I have just started in the world of web development, I am working with react js, I am currently using react table where a column adds a button to show the detail of each row (Showing that detail in a modal window). I manage to get the data but I can't filter only the data corresponding to the row, any idea how I could achieve it? I have tried modifying and comparing the object at runtime however it doesn't work for me

Table,
[image: Table]

Modal details,
[image: Modal details img]

**CODE**
Modal.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal';
import Button from "../../atoms/Button"
import DetailTravel from "../../organisms/Travels/Detail"
function getModalStyle() {
  const top = 50;
  const left = 50 ;
  return {
    top: `${top}%`,
    left: `${left}%`,
    transform: `translate(-${top}%, -${left}%)`,
  };
}
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '80%',
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    border: '2px solid #000',
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
  },
}));

export default function SimpleModal() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  // getModalStyle is not a pure function, we roll the style only on the first render
  const [modalStyle] = React.useState(getModalStyle);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
  
  const body = (
    <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper}>
      <h2 id="simple-modal-title"> Detalle de viaje</h2>
      
      <div>
      <p id="simple-modal-description">
      <DetailTravel></DetailTravel>
      </p>
      <Button type="button" onClick={handleClose}>
        Cerrar
      </Button >
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

TableDetail.js

```
import Table from "components/templates/Table";
import useGetTravels from "hooks/travels/useGetTravels";
import columnsDefinition from "./columns"

export default () => {
  const { travels, isLoadingData } = useGetTravels();
const datos = new Object(travels);
 
console.log(travels);
  return (
    <div>
            <Table columnsDefinition={columnsDefinition} data={datos} isLoadingData={isLoadingData} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

ColumnsDetailTable.js

```
export default [
  {
    Header: "Cliente",
    accessor: "ClienteNombre",
    disableFilters: true
  },
  {
    Header: "Conductor",
    accessor: "ChoferNombre",
    disableFilters: true
  },
  {
    Header: "Origen",
    accessor: "OrigenDireccion",
    disableFilters: true
  },
  {
    Header: "Destino",
    accessor: "DestinoDireccion",
    disableFilters: true
  },
  {
    Header: "Distancia",
    accessor: "Distancia.kilometers",
    disableFilters: true
  },
  {
    Header: "Estatus",
    accessor: "Estatus",
    disableFilters: true
  },

  {
    Header: "Metodo de pago",
    accessor: "MetodoPago",
    disableFilters: true
  },

  {
    Header: "Monto",
    accessor: "Costo",
    disableFilters: true
  },
  {
    Header: "Latitud",
    accessor: "OrigenLatitude",
    disableFilters: true
  },
  {
    Header: "Longitud",
    accessor: "OrigenLongitude",
    disableFilters: true
  },
  {
    Header: "Fecha",
    accessor: "FechaSolicitud",
    disableFilters: true
  },
  {
    Header: "Marca Vehiculo",
    accessor: "VehiculoMarca",
    disableFilters: true
  },
  {
    Header: "Modelo",
    accessor: "VehiculoModelo",
    disableFilters: true
  },  
  {
    Header: "Placas",
    accessor: "VehiculoPlacas",
    disableFilters: true
  },

];
```

ColumnsTableTemplate.js

```
import React from "react";
import { H4 } from "components/atoms/Text";
import convertDate from "shared/convertDate";
import convertMoney from "shared/convertMoney";
import {SelectColumnFilter,SelectColumnDate } from '../../../shared/filter'
import Mode from "components/templates/Modal"
export default [
  {
    Header: "Cliente",
    accessor: "ClienteNombre",
  },
  {
    Header: "Conductor",
    accessor: "ChoferNombre",
  },
  {
    Header: "Origen",
    accessor: "OrigenDireccion",
    disableFilters: true
  },
  {
    Header: "Destino",
    accessor: "DestinoDireccion",
    disableFilters: true
  },
  {
    Header: "Distancia",
    accessor: "Distancia.kilometers",
    Cell: (cellProps) => {
      return <H4 colorVariant="secondary">{cellProps.value + " KM"}</H4>;
    },
    disableFilters: true
  },
  {
    Header: "Estatus",
    accessor: "Estatus",
    Filter:SelectColumnFilter
  },

  {
    Header: "Metodo de pago",
    accessor: "MetodoPago",
    disableFilters: true
  },

  {
    Header: "Monto",
    accessor: "Costo",
    Cell: (cellProps) => {
      return (
        <H4 colorVariant="secondary">{convertMoney(cellProps.value || 0)}</H4>
      );
    },
    disableFilters: true
  },

  {
    Header: "Fecha",
    accessor: "FechaSolicitud",
    Cell: (cellProps) => {
      return <H4 colorVariant="secondary">{convertDate(cellProps.value)}</H4>;
    },
    Filter:SelectColumnDate
  },
  {
    Header: "Detalle",
    accessor: "Link",
    Cell:e => <Mode></Mode>,
    disableFilters: true
  }
```